# logkeys log file has wiered output

Tags: 15.10, log

I have a Ubuntu 15.10 install and recently installed logkeys. and I followed up with the log file with after installation and creating the log file.

> tail --follow test.log

it generates weired output. eg: when *s* is pressed *as* is displayed(the first line of alphabets in the keyboard prints double alphabet.the other two line prints the preceding key and the key pressed) . i tried to set the language to us English but it doesn't help. i followed the following page.

> https://github.com/kernc/logkeys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to change the keymap that `logkeys` uses.**

You have to understand that `logkeys` is made in such a way that it can work on different keyboards all over the world. These keyboards come in different languages, accents etc. `logkeys` comes with a default keymap. I, for one, found that this keymap did not print output correctly for me too, and hence, I changed this keymap.

First, try running `logkeys` with the `--us-keymap` option.

If this doesn't solve your problem, read the "Keymap Format" section from the `logkeys` manpage to see how it works. After that, do:

```
sudo logkeys --export-keymap ~/my_keymap
```

and try fixing this file by experimenting with it. The way you do this is to change this file, and use this file as your keymap by doing:

```
sudo logkeys -s -m ~/my_keymap
```

If you can't seem to fix it by yourself, provide the output of the `my_keymap` file that we created above, here, and we will try to fix the problem.

PS: Try out the `--no-func-keys` option to make reading the log easier.

Comment: hi, solved it.thanks for the quick reply :) strangely it worked when i used the -u switch today and did not work when i tried yesterday.

Comment: hi, i am terribly sorry but i have finally figured out what the problem is :P i read somewhere that the data stored on the log file is raw and cant be used directly hence my question should really have been how to make use of that saved text on my log files. help much appreciated